# Every Possible Combination instead of random sampling in code in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, combinations

If I wanted to perform the same analysis I have below within the code provided, but instead of doing a random sampling of rows from my original data, I actually would want to run the test for every possible combination there is. For this example, there are 20 possible combinations. Would anyone be able to help me figure this out?  I know I can no longer use the "replicate" command, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to make this work properly. Thanks!

Sample data is provided below, with the code:

```
dput(A)
structure(list(Box.Z = c(972.729751840742, 934.814227158535, 
996.933797909408, 791.217703626463, 784.234752589183, 783.659378596087
), Box.DC.gm = c(19.3350173135753, 19.2528485621378, 17.9726391261602, 
19.8067268125686, 19.6961540482885, 19.2498052750475), Box.CR = c(0.0184126042027551, 
0.0211500857551233, 0.0175062024694362, 0.0337401180409656, 0.0346889237620637, 
0.0347098429625015), Box.DC.ww = c(1.24742047184357, 1.25188518062349, 
1.17616931947406, 1.4929693577313, 1.44061448275529, 1.40750828224021
), Box.DC.gd = c(18.0875968417318, 18.0009633815143, 16.7964698066862, 
18.3137574548373, 18.2555395655332, 17.8422969928073), Box.DC.w = c(6.8965517241379, 
6.95454545454546, 7.00247928886737, 8.15217391304348, 7.89138265447493, 
7.88860471724921)), .Names = c("Box.Z", "Box.DC.gm", "Box.CR", 
"Box.DC.ww", "Box.DC.gd", "Box.DC.w"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

A <- setNames(data.frame(A), c("Box.Z", "Box.DC.gm", "Box.CR", "Box.DC.ww", "Box.DC.gd", "Box.DC.w"))


randco <- function(A) {
rowsel <- sample(6,3)
B <- A[rowsel,]
C <- A[-rowsel, ]

Boxgm <- C$Box.DC.gm
Boxww <- C$Box.DC.ww
Boxgd <- C$Box.DC.gd
Boxw  <- C$Box.DC.w

EDGgm <- predict(lm(Box.DC.gm ~ Box.Z, data=B),newdata=C[,"Box.Z",drop=FALSE])
EDGww <- predict(lm(Box.DC.ww ~ Box.CR, data=B),newdata=C[,"Box.CR",drop=FALSE])

EDGgd <- EDGgm - EDGww
EDGw <- (EDGww*100/EDGgd)  

rmse.gm <- sqrt(mean((EDGgm-Boxgm)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
rmse.gd <- sqrt(mean((EDGgd-Boxgd)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
rmse.ww <- sqrt(mean((EDGww-Boxww)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
rmse.w <-  sqrt(mean((EDGw-Boxw)^2, na.rm = TRUE))

list(gm=rmse.gm, gd=rmse.gd, ww=rmse.ww, w=rmse.w)

}


Z <- t(replicate(10, randco(A)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `combn(6,3)` to generate all possible combinations of 6 choose 3, then use columns of that as the row indexes (rowsel in your code)

```
randco <- function(A, rowsel){
    # Your program here
} 

Z <- apply(combn(6,3), 2, randco, A=A)
```

Comment: Excellent. This is much simpler than I imagined. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know how I can make my output display in 4 columns? instead of 1 line of output?

Comment: You might try returning a vector instead of a list. Try changing the `list(gm=` line at the bottom to `c(gm=`